# Symfony: set custom data attribute on child form for use in twig template

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, symfony

I have the following setup. 
- A Day Entity
- A Day form which has its own fields

To the Day form I like to add a calculated 'total' value that is based on six Day attributes. I have already successfully created a class that does so. So the main question is: **how to link the calculated data to each Day form**.

I show below only the necessary code, so if you miss something, its not shown.

DayEntity is default, with a bunch of fields.

DayType form:

```
    class DayType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('field');
        // etc, bunch of fields

        // Here I want to add a calculated field. How to do it?
        // The result is retrieved from my service, with a function: calculateTotal($day);
        }
    }

I have already a service which does the necessary computation:

public function calculateTotal(Day $day)
{
    // Some magic here ;-)

    return $returnDateInterval;
}
```

In Twig I like to do something like:

```
{{ dayform.vars.data.calculatedTotal|date('H:i') }}
// or
{{ dayform.calculatedTotal|date('H:i') }}
```

Comment: You can just pass your service to your formType as an option ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have added the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer in.... the great Symfony docs! [Defining your forms as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services)

So what I did was modifying my service.yml:

```
app.subscriber.calculatetotal:
    class: AppBundle\Form\EventListener\CalculateTotalFieldSubscriber
    arguments: ["@app.manager.day"]


app.form.day:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\DayType
    arguments: ["@app.subscriber.calculatetotal"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

As you can see I also added a Form EventListener which listens on PRE_SUBMIT and POST_SET_DATA to alter my non mapped 'total' field.

In the DayType.php Form:

```
private $calculateTotalFieldSubscriber;

public function __construct(CalculateTotalFieldSubscriber    $calculateTotalFieldSubscriber)
{
    $this->calculateTotalFieldSubscriber = $calculateTotalFieldSubscriber;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    // I do not save this field to the database, so mapped is set to false
    ->add('total', TimeType::class, array(
        'mapped' => false
    ))
    $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->calculateTotalFieldSubscriber);
}
```

The calculateTotalFieldSubscriber is default, listening to two events.